# Statistics for iptable best pratices?

Tags: linux, configuration, iptables, best-practices

Looking for statistics on IPtable best pratices - appears that a server like www.cloudflare.com would parse iptables and look for gaps and trends in iptable configs - but don't think they'd publish their findings. **FYI:** I just heard about cloudflare, haven't used it, and have nothing to do with them. If you're aware of other services like cloudflare, please post links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well - script it.. use `iptables -nvxL` as input and pump it to [rrd](http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool/) database. or let others do it for you - [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) or [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) can do it with plugins:

- [munin](http://www.munin-monitoring.org/browser/trunk/plugins/node.d.linux/ip_.in)
- [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/downloads/scripts/iptables.pl.txt)
- zabbix - well it can too. just google

one thing to keep in mind - 32bit counters nowadays tend to be not enough. if you count bytes they might flip over in less than monitoring interval [eg 5 min]. so remember to store and read data as 64bit integers.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare -btw has an excellent apache mod that will allow your own stats to continue to parse.